# For User X, serve non-cached version of profile X and cached-versions of other (!X) profiles ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching

In my ASP.NET MVC project I have a `UserController` with it's `Index` action accepting `userName` as a parameter to server profiles based on their usernames. The profiles do quite a lot of crunching behind the scenes so I am thinking of an efficient way of caching. My initial thought is something along these lines:

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated() || (Request.IsAuthenticated() && userName != User.Identity.Name))
    //browser cache
else
    //no cache
end if
```

So User `X` receives a non-cached version for his own profile, but a browser-cached version for all other profiles. Non-logged in users also receive browser-cached versions of profiles (though I'm not sure of a good way to go about User X visiting his profile while not logged in and then revisiting from the same browser while logged in). If I'm barking up the wrong tree I'm open to other suggestions.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To give all users the same website experience, i would recommend, that you give all users (regardless of logged in or out) the same content.

So when you have a cached version of a profile, then ship this profile to the requesting user. When you don't have the profile, then get it from the database.

With this approach you should invalidate a profile in the cache, when:

- the lifetime exceeds
- the profile is dirty (was updated in the mean time)

If it is dirty, you could save the updated version in the cache after the update succeeds.